# Pygame get_pressed()

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, keyboard-input

I've been checking a lot of tutorials, I've been testing it myself, I read the official papers a hundred of times.
How the heck does `pygame.key.get_pressed()` work?
It looks like it isn't used at all in gaming. Can you suggest me some raw code, no ketchup where I can get a good example?

Comment: Could you please better explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get_pressed is just another way of getting keypresses

You could do this in an event pumper:

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_w]:
    # Do stuff
```

Although just using the KEYDOWN event is better as it adds a delay between presses.:

```
# At the beginning of the loop...
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_w:
            # Do stuff
```